# how to fix a hole in a photoscanned rock?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

[image]i'd like to fix the hole in this photoscanned model so it look complete

Comment: This might not be that simple. You can fix the mesh by editing it, but then you'll need to correct the image texture UV mapping to make it work with the corrected mesh.

Answer (score 1):

if it is using a UV texture you can use the clone brush in texture paint mode and copy texture from other places (using clone brush, control + left mouse button to choose area to clone, and then paint with left mouse button and drag)